# How to access container logs of a script executed with StartContainer using the go SDK from docker inc

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

## Motivation

I'm running this command inside the container:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  --mount type=volume,src=synapse-data,dst=/data \
  -e SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=my.matrix.host \
  -e SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=yes \
  matrixdotorg/synapse:latest generate
```

Based on https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/tree/v1.56.0/docker

## Docker SDK usage

And I'm using this abstraction: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ContainerCreate

As a general concept I want to use:

```
AutoRemove: true,
```

The point is to automate/enforce containers deletion after use, for instance, if the setup exits unexpectedly. I'm also using a container name: *server_setup_temporary_container* which *hints* the user that this is used during setup and is meant to be temporary. In case the setup did not shutdown the container, the user can do this and the bound volumes are freed.

## My problem with this generate script

I can't use https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/v20.10.18/client/container_logs.go#L36 as the container exits once it finished executing the *generate*. Therefore I can't access the logs at all as they are already deleted.

In contrast, this works well with the postgresql container, as it runs as a daemon and needs explicit shutdown. The same concept fails with only executing a script!

I don't know how to continue here.

A few thoughts I had:

- after generate execute a 'sleep 3600' and then explicitly shut the container down as well
- try to get the logs from ContainerStart or ContainerCreate directly but studying the API this is probably not implemented this way

What I would not want is to remove the **AutoRemove: true** concept.

## The source code

### Using my StartContainer abstraction

```
// Start and run container
containerId, err := s.dockerClient.myStartContainer(docker.ContainerStartConfig{
    Image: matrixImage,
    Volumes: []docker.ContainerVolume{
        docker.ContainerVolume{
            Source: volume,
            Target: "/data",
        },
    },
    Env: []string{
        fmt.Sprintf("SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=%s", domain),
        "SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=no",
    },
    Cmds: []string{
        "generate",
    },
})
```

### StartContainer abstraction

```
func (c *Client) myStartContainer(cfg ContainerStartConfig) (string, error) {
    if c.client == nil {
        return "", errors.New(noClientErr)
    }

    if len(cfg.Image) == 0 {
        return "", errors.New(noImageErr)
    }

    containerConfig := container.Config{
        Image: cfg.Image,
    }
    hostConfig := container.HostConfig{
        AutoRemove: true,
    }
    if cfg.Env != nil {
        containerConfig.Env = cfg.Env
    }
    if cfg.Cmds != nil {
        containerConfig.Cmd = make(strslice.StrSlice, len(cfg.Cmds))
        for i, _cmd := range cfg.Cmds {
            containerConfig.Cmd[i] = _cmd
        }
    }
    if cfg.Volumes != nil {
        hostConfig.Mounts = make([]mount.Mount, len(cfg.Volumes))
        for i, v := range cfg.Volumes {
            hostConfig.Mounts[i] = mount.Mount{
                Type:   "volume",
                Source: v.Source,
                Target: v.Target,
            }
        }
    }
    var networkingConfig *network.NetworkingConfig
    if cfg.Networks != nil {
        networkingConfig = &network.NetworkingConfig{EndpointsConfig: map[string]*network.EndpointSettings{}}
        for _, nw := range cfg.Networks {
            n := nw.Name
            networkingConfig.EndpointsConfig[n] = &network.EndpointSettings{Aliases: nw.Aliases}
        }
    }
    cont, err := c.client.ContainerCreate(
        c.ctx,
        &containerConfig,
        &hostConfig,
        networkingConfig,
        nil,
        "server_setup_temporary_container",
    )
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    colorlogger.Log.Info("Container ID of "+colorlogger.LYellow, cfg.Image, colorlogger.CLR+" is "+cont.ID)
    if err := c.client.ContainerStart(c.ctx, cont.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return cont.ID, nil
}
```

## Greater scenario

I'm executing this setup in order to configure the containers which are later executed with 'docker compose' as some of the setups require explicit changes to the containers and can't be done declaratively.

Comment: Can you `defer` a call to delete the container, rather than have Docker delete it immediately on completion?  That would give you an opportunity to retrieve the logs before it's deleted, but still (usually) cause it to be automatically be cleaned up; it is a little less robust than `AutoRemove: true`.

Comment: ("...require explicit changes to the containers..." is probably a bug; this approach won't work in clustered environments like Kubernetes where a Pod can be deleted and recreated on a different node outside your control.  You also might look into making your containers be able to do their own setup, maybe in an entrypoint wrapper script or something similar.  Can you run this "generate" step in a Dockerfile or as part of another container's startup sequence, for example?)